# Move partition and extend backwards

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning

How can I move a partition backwards on the disk to remove the gap of free space, and then extend a partition backwards to fill that space?

Ex:  move `/dev/sda3` (swap) backwards to 253093888, and then extend `/dev/sda4` to start at 271093464 (the new end of `/dev/sda3`)

[image: disk layout]

Preferably an option that doesn't need to be booted from a live USB to work.

Comment: *"How can I move a partition backwards on the disk..."* -- You mean *forward*, towards the beginning of the disk.  You could use GParted by booting a LiveCD from CD/DVD or USB flash drive.  But moving a partition is very slow, and you need to make backups.  Unless a lot of files are involved, I've found copying to another drive (and then back after deleting & creating partitions) much faster.

Comment: All the above and more: **It's a `swap` partition!** Just remove it and create it again where you need. Don't forget to `swapoff` before deleting as you won't be able to if swap is being used.